# convert Audio file to text file c# library or source code

Tags: c#, java

I just want to know if there is any built in libraries or external libraries in Java or C# that allow me to take an audio file and parse it and extract the text from it.

Comment: extract the binary stream as text or the actual spoken words? oh, and what have you tried/researched?

Comment: What text do you expect to get out of an audio file?

Comment: In C# there is the [System.Speech.Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Search on 'speech/voice recognition'.  But you have a long road ahead, to a working application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in .NET speech recognition APIs to accomplish this. MSDN has a set of complete samples that read an audio file and then write the recognised speech to the console. With a little bit of work they can be modified to output to a plain text file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtoaudiostream.aspx